# How to make a div slide into the viewport, without knowing its height

Tags: jquery, absolute, slideup

I need the CSS code for the green box. The green box should be almost complete invisible, if you click on the visible area, then the rest should slide up.

The height of the green element should be unknown. I'm currently adding `style="bottom: -27em"` manually

It is important that this element stays sticky at the bottom even if the window is resized.

How can I accomplish this task?

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body style="width: 300px" class="overflow-hidden h-screen float-right m-4 relative">





  <!-- Trigger Button -->
  <div id="time-trigger" class="fixed" style="bottom: -27em" data-state="closed">

    <div style="width: 300px" class=" w-6 cursor-pointer flex rounded-t-lg bg-violet-800 justify-center items-center text-white leading-10">
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke-width="1.5" stroke="currentColor" class="w-6 h-6 mr-2">
          <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" d="M12 6v6h4.5m4.5 0a9 9 0 11-18 0 9 9 0 0118 0z" />
        </svg>
      <span>Time Trigger</span>
    </div>


    <div class=" bg-white text-black p-4">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata
      sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea
      rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
    </div>
  </div>



  <script>
    $("#time-trigger").on("click", function() {

      if ($("#time-trigger").attr('data-state') == "closed") {
        $("#time-trigger").css("bottom", "");
        $("#time-trigger").attr("data-state", "open")

      } else {
        $("#time-trigger").css("bottom", "-27em");
        $("#time-trigger").attr("data-state", "closed")
      }

    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

[image]

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research - [search SO for answers](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+slide+div+from+outside+viewport+site%3Astackoverflow.com).  If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [\[<>\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. You're expected to [try to solve the problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users). Please update your question to show what you have already tried in a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). For further information, please see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask), and take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) :)

Comment: i added the information, thank you for your feedback!

Comment: Why not just use `.height()` to get the element's height? See [jQuery docs: height()](https://api.jquery.com/height/). BTW: StackOverflow can also run snippets, you don't need a jsfiddle. Use the `<>` button, add jQuery with the select boxes on the left.

Comment: @PeterKrebs thank you, is there a solution without jQuery? If not then ill have to go with this solution. The reason why, i would like to have it without Javascript is, because i dont want no flashing when the site loads, or objects repositioning itself.

Comment: If you see flashing or sudden repositioning it means some JS could be optimized and run sooner or load faster etc.. But very old computers could still see a bit of movement, yes. Could you use `top` by default and then switch to `top: auto; bottom: 0` when clicked? I also assume using classes renders a bit faster than inline styles.

Comment: It seems to work well (using Firefox). What is your problem? Can you make your question more specific?